# Failed to migrate Jersey redirect to Spring redirect

Tags: java, spring, redirect, iframe, jersey

I have the following jersey code to redirect inside an iframe (redirectLink is full URL in same domain):

```
private Response redirect(String redirectLink) {
   return Response.seeOther(new URI(redirectLink)).build();
}
```

I tried migration to Spring using [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html):

```
public ResponseEntity<String> confirm(String redirectLink) {
   return ResponseEntity.created(new URI(redirectLink)).build();
}
```

But I see a blank page instead of redirect

- I logged that that full URL is correct

Example in documentation:

> ```
> URI location = ...;
> return ResponseEntity.created(location).header("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue").body("Hello World");
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded using [RedirectView](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html) (using partial/relative path to domain)

```
public RedirectView  confirm(String partialPath) {
   return new RedirectView(partialPath);
}
```

> View that redirects to an absolute, context relative, or current request relative URL